# Add class to a DOM element on click

Tags: android, jquery, xamarin, webview

I need to add a class to element on click. The click gets registered, however, when I try to add a class to the target it has no effect.

```
<ellipse data-part-id="147" class="body_part" cx="112.75" cy="25" rx="20" ry="20" transform="rotate(0 ,111.663,25)"></ellipse>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.body_part').click(function (event) {
        //has no effect
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        //has no effect either
        $(event.target).addClass('clicked');
        //works & returns the value
        $(event.target).attr('data-part-id');
    });
});
```

When I try to access the object to get some data, it works with no issue. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What makes you think it has no effect? It works for me

Comment: The defined style doesn't change and when I try to retreive `class` attribute it doesn't contain the class

Comment: Try starting with a bare object (remove `cx="112.75" cy="25" rx="20" ry="20" transform="rotate(0 ,111.663,25)`). Give the CSS some really obvious effects. Does it change anything?

Comment: Some of the attributes are required so I can't remove them. I tried adding class on different element types such as `h1` and it works with no issue, but the moment I try to manipulate classes on`ellipse`, no luck

Comment: Can we see the css you are trying to work with?

Comment: So the issue seems to be  that jQuery isn't able to manipulate content of SVG